# Phaser groups moving each child independantly

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so i have a phaser group

```js
this.cows = this.physics.add.group({
      key: "cow",
      repeat: 2,
      setXY: { x: 160, y: 1500, stepX: 32 },
    });

    this.cows.children.iterate(function (child) {
      child.setSize(20, 10, true);
      child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.2, 0.4));
    });
```

I plan to update the movement of every child in the update function, so how would i make sure every child has a different amount of movement in a different direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your use case you could simply use, a property `destination` which the `child` wants to reach, and when it is reached, just set a new `destination`.

**Here a short demo showcaing this:**
*(it uses Vector's, not everybody likes/understtands them, but they are concise)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Random Movment')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('cow', 10, 10);
    
    this.cows = this.physics.add.group({
      key: "cow",
      repeat: 2,
      setXY: { x: 50, y: 50, stepX: 32 },
    });

    this.cows.children.iterate(function (child) {
      child.setSize(10, 10, true);
      child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.2, 0.4));
      child.speed = Phaser.Math.Between(30, 50);
      child.destination = { x: child.x , y: child.y};
    });
}

function update(){
    
    this.cows.children.iterate(function (child) {
        if(Phaser.Math.Distance.BetweenPoints(child.body.position, child.destination) <= 20){
            //new destination
            child.destination = { x:Phaser.Math.Between(50, 200), y:Phaser.Math.Between(50, 150)};
    
            // Setup velocity
            let vector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(child.destination);
            vector.subtract(child.body.position)
                 .setLength(child.speed);
              
            child.setVelocity(vector.x, vector.y);
        }
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```